# DRUPAL E-mail Form Sender Name Instead Of E-mail with Domain Basis?

Tags: drupal-7

$default_from = variable_get('site_mail', ini_get('sendmail_from'));

if($message['from'] == $default_from){

$message['from'] = '"'. variable_get('site_name', 'Drupal') .'" <'. $default_from .'>';

$message['headers']['From'] = $message['from'];

Answer (score 0):

Example

function hook_mail_alter(&$message) {

if($message['id'] == "put_id" && $domain_id == 368){

$default_from = variable_get('site_mail', ini_get('sendmail_from'));

if($message['from'] == $default_from){

$message['from'] = '"'. variable_get('site_name', 'Drupal') .'" <'. $default_from .'>';

$message['headers']['From'] = $message['from'];

}

}

}